# Doubt regarding Trace class operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, compact-operators

Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces. Recall that a closed subspace $V\subset B(H,K)$ is called a ternary ring of operators(TRO) if  $xy^*z \in V$ for all $x,y,z \in V$.

> Let $H$ and $K$ be Hilbert spaces and let  $\mathscr{I}_1(H,K)$ denotes the space of trace class operators.  Is $\mathscr{I}_1(H,K)$ a TRO?

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain? Is it obvious for downvoter?

Comment: Please show your effort.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy:  Actually I was trying to construct counterexample but I could not make one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace class operators $H \to K$ are not closed in $B(H,K)$ (with respect to the norm topology). Indeed, every finite-dimensional operator is trace class. Then choose a compact operator that is not trace class. Since every compact operator (between Hilbert spaces!) is the norm-limit of finite rank operators, we can conclude the first claim.

On the other hand, the identity $xy^*z \in \mathscr{T}(H,K)$ does hold for all $x,y,z \in \mathscr{T}(H,K)$ because the trace class operators form an ideal.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by an ideal in B(H,K)?

Comment: If $u: H \to K$ and $v: K \to L$ are bounded operators and $u$ is trace class, then $vu$ is trace-class. Similarly for the other side